SQL Anywhere BEFORE INSERT Trigger
Good morning. I am working with SQL Anywhere 16. I have a before-insert trigger where I need to modify some data. How do I reference the inserted record's field to change the data? According to the documentation, "The REFERENCING NEW clause allows you to modify the new row in a BEFORE trigger before the insert or update operation takes place." How may this be accomplished?
I have the following trigger added to the database. When it is called, I get an error "Table 'NEWTRANVAL' not found.
CREATE TRIGGER TRANVALDateGL 
BEFORE INSERT ON TRANVAL
REFERENCING NEW AS NEWTRANVAL
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   DECLARE @GLStatus INT;
   SELECT GLSTATUS INTO @GLStatus FROM NEWTRANVAL;

   IF @GLSTATUS = 10223716 OR @GLSTATUS = 10223718 OR @GLSTATUS = 10223719 THEN
      BEGIN
      SET NEWTRANVAL.DateGL=SQLToJulian(GetDate());
      END
   ELSE
      BEGIN
      SET NEWTRANVAL.DateGL = 0;
      END
   END IF;
END;

Thank you for the help!

My error was on the SELECT statement. This is not needed. In case others run across, this, here is the correct trigger code.
CREATE TRIGGER TRANVALDateGLInsert
BEFORE INSERT ON TRANVAL
REFERENCING NEW AS NEWTRANVAL
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF NEWTRANVAL.GLSTATUS = 10223716 OR NEWTRANVAL.GLSTATUS = 10223718 OR NEWTRANVAL.GLSTATUS = 10223719 THEN
      BEGIN
      SET NEWTRANVAL.DateGL=SQLToJulian(GetDate());
      END
   ELSE
      BEGIN
      SET NEWTRANVAL.DateGL = 0;
      END
   END IF;
END;
GO

